# Getting the most frequent element in a factor in R

Tags: string, r, frequency

I have a set of strings in a R variable, when I check the class, it says it is a factor.
eg.

```
mySet<-c("abc","abc","def","abc","def","efg","abc")
```

I want to get the string which occurs the maximum number of times in this set(i.e."abc" in this case).

I understand one approach is to use the `hist()` but I am facing data type issues and since I'm new to R I wasn't able to crack this one by myself.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Depending on the size of your data and the frequency at which you need to do such an exercise, you might want to spend some time writing a more efficient function. Underlying `table` is `tabulate`, which is much faster, and can thus lead to a function like the following:

```
MaxTable <- function(InVec, mult = FALSE) {
  if (!is.factor(InVec)) InVec <- factor(InVec)
  A <- tabulate(InVec)
  if (isTRUE(mult)) {
    levels(InVec)[A == max(A)]
  } 
  else levels(InVec)[which.max(A)]
}
```

This function is designed to also identify when there are multiple values for the max values. Compare the following:

```
mySet <- c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C")
## Your question indicates that you have factors,
##   but your sample code is a character vector
mySetF <- factor(mySet) ## Just as an example

## @BrodieG's answer
fun1 <- function(InVec) {
  names(which.max(table(InVec)))
}

## @sgibb's answer
fun2 <- function(InVec) {
  m <- which.max(table(as.character(InVec)))
  as.character(InVec)[m]
}

fun1(mySet)
# [1] "A"
fun2(mySet)
# [1] "A"
MaxTable(mySet)
# [1] "A"
MaxTable(mySet, mult = TRUE)
# [1] "A" "B"

library(microbenchmark)    
microbenchmark(fun1(mySet), fun2(mySet), MaxTable(mySet), MaxTable(mySetF))
# Unit: microseconds
#              expr     min       lq   median       uq      max neval
#       fun1(mySet) 291.457 297.1845 302.2080 313.1235 3008.108   100
#       fun2(mySet) 296.388 302.0775 311.3170 321.5260 1367.137   100
#   MaxTable(mySet) 172.463 180.8755 184.8355 189.9700 1947.700   100
#  MaxTable(mySetF)  34.510  38.1545  44.6045  46.6695   95.341   100
```

At the small vector level, this function is more efficient. This is even more obvious with `factor` vectors. How about with bigger vectors?

```
set.seed(1)
medSet <- sample(c(LETTERS, letters), 1e5, TRUE)
medSetF <- factor(medSet)

fun1(medSet)
# [1] "E"
fun2(medSet) ### Wrong Answer!!!
# [1] "D"
MaxTable(medSet)
# [1] "E"

microbenchmark(fun1(medSet), MaxTable(medSet), MaxTable(medSetF))
# Unit: microseconds
#               expr       min        lq     median        uq       max neval
#       fun1(medSet) 14222.846 14350.957 14484.4490 14600.490 34810.174   100
#   MaxTable(medSet)  7787.761  7860.248  7917.3455  8019.068  9762.884   100
#  MaxTable(medSetF)   501.733   529.257   570.0735   587.936  1469.994   100
```

I've dropped @sgibb's function from the benchmarks (it runs in about the same time as `fun1()`) since it returns the wrong answer.

One last benchmark....

```
set.seed(3)
bigSet <- sample(c(LETTERS, letters), 1e7, TRUE)
bigSetF <- factor(bigSet)
microbenchmark(fun1(bigSet), MaxTable(bigSet), MaxTable(bigSetF), times = 10)
# Unit: milliseconds
#               expr        min         lq     median         uq        max neval
#       fun1(bigSet) 1519.37503 1612.10290 1648.36473 1789.02965 1932.41073    10
#   MaxTable(bigSet)  782.01856  791.86408  834.35764  894.60535 1019.28747    10
#  MaxTable(bigSetF)   48.56459   48.76492   49.25444   49.93911   50.20404    10
```

Comment: How does it handle ties?

Comment: @Hack-R, That's what the `mult = TRUE` setting is for. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Yea, I guess I didn't look at it closely enough. I can probably answer my own question with `?tabulate`, but I guess I meant if `mult` was false but two levels were equally frequent, then I was wondering what it would return.

Comment: Your `MaxTable` is a very useful function, however it fails if it is given a factor, but not every level is in the data. In that case, `levels(InVec)[A == max(A)]` has more levels on the left side than bools in the subset. Use `InVec <- factor(as.character(InVec))` to prevent this possibility.

Answer (score 6):

Variation on sqibb:

```
names(which.max(table(mySet)))
# [1] "abc"
```

Comment: This isn't a variation of @sgibb's answer. It's the correct version of his answer.

Comment: Caveat: This won't handle cases in which two values are present equally often.

Answer (score 0):

repeated <- function(x) as(names(which.max(table(x))), mode(x))
repeated(a)
where a is a vector of either words or numbers